# How can I map this WCF functionality to my REST web api?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, wcf, rest

Greetings I have a WCF service, and basically what the API users do to create a book is following:

```
var Book = new DtoBook()
                {
                    OpenInModal = false,
                    CallToActionUrl = "url"
                    Status = NotificationStatus.Unseen,
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                    Type = NotificationType.Type,
                    Message = "test,
                };
                BookManager.Instance.Add(Book);
```

I have users to basically do the same thing but instead on the client-side.

I have created a POST method already that looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Add(List<DtoBook> Books)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    BookManager.Instance.Add(Books);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Books);
    return response;
}
```

So when I enter the url I get following in my console:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'test.Controllers.NotificationsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
```

My question is what do I need to do so the user can type the properties of the dToBook class and then the POST happens and the book gets added. I guess right now it just tries to add it without any properties.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the method is post, for sample:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Add([FromBody]List<DtoBook> Books)
{
   // code
}
```